# EventKit - Event Location, Notes, and organizer properties are empty

Tags: iphone, ipad, objective-c++, ios5, eventkit

I'm trying to fetch some events from the calender using EventKit, and that on ios 5 beta 6.
From some reason, all the fields of the event is empty except the participants, title and dates.
No location, no organizer, and no notes, although those events have this data.

What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [EKEvent eventIdentifier returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768751/ekevent-eventidentifier-returns-null)